# Restore Ubuntu Upgrades Installation

Tags: 16.04, upgrade, dpkg, 18.04

Once I installed Ubuntu 16.04LTS, followed by Upgrading to Ubuntu 18.04LTS. After all the  new **Ubuntu 18.04LTS** package get downloaded, Unfortunately new Installation get Interrupted.

When I tried to power on my computer it gives back the black screen with message **dpkg failed**.

How can i restore the Installation?

Comment: If you installed Ubuntu 16.04 just before, it would be better to reinstall 18.04 from scratch instead of upgrading.

Answer (score 0):

As we know Ubuntu can manager 6 users in command Line at once, while the user number 7 is the only one who can user the Interface.

1. Simply Click **Ctrl + Alt + F1** then login by administrator username and password.
2. Type  **sudo dpkg --configure -a**
3. Then press Enter, the upgrade package installation will continue, then **reboot**

Comment: I think they switched things up for Ubuntu 17.10 or 18.04 and they use 1 and 2 for the GUI now, so they might need Ctrl+Alt+F3.